# Blazor Server in Microservice Architecture - No Controllers

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

The idea is to not have any kind of Controller and fully use the SignalR Connection that is already existing in Blazor Server. Then communicate via some mechanism with other microservices (gRPC, Kafka, Redis Streams etc). Those microservices do what they need to do (access database, business logic and so on) and return the outcome.

I would like to implement something like this :
[image]

I'm currently facing three issues regarding Authentication, Authorization and the hidden SignalR Connection:

1. Identify which method is being called. The Authentication Hub Filter is able to "intercept" any event from the Frontend. But lets assume I add "@onclick="LoginUser"" to my button. I'm not able to identify "LoginUser" getting called. HubInvocationContext does not provide that.
2. Role based Authorization with the claims inside my JWT.
3. Access to the Hub Client. I would like to store data to a specific client just like I could with a regular SignalR Hub and Client.

Suggestions to any point and/or to the whole thing are welcome.
Regards!